# Is it possible to add Maven phase to IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Is it possible to add the "integration-test" phase that Maven offer in IntelliJ? Or does that make no sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "add" it?  You can run it from IntelliJ, if that's what you mean.

Comment: How, I don't see that phase listed?

Comment: He means that it is not listed by default in the Maven Projects pane. You must untick `Show Basic Phases Only` to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `pom.xml` includes the Failsafe plugin in its build configuration (see the [Failsafe usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html)) then in the **Maven Projects** view in IntelliJ, you should see **[ProjectName] -> Plugins -> failsafe -> failsafe:integration-test**.  Double-click on it to run the `integration-test` goal (note it's a goal, not a phase) or right-click on it and click "Create..." to add an IntelliJ run configuration for the integration-test goal.

Comment: Better is to call mvn verify to run the whole lifecycle incl. integration-test cause may be you have used some kind of setup for the integration-test (pre-integration-test life-cycle phase).

Comment: I fully agree with @khmarbaise.  Also, it seems that in IDEA 11+ the way you show "integration-tests" is to uncheck the "Show Basic Phases Only" option.

Comment: "the Maven Projects view in IntelliJ" -- what is that?

Comment: @jameshfisher: I'm not sure how to say it any clearer.  There is a tool window in IntelliJ IDEA called Maven Projects.  That is what I'm talking about.